# how to use "read" command read a whole line data which end with <CR><LF> under bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file like this :

```
1 2 3 <CR><LF>
1 2 3 <CR><LF>
1 2 3 <CR><LF>
```

what should I do to get "1 2 3" everytime I read a line from it ?

Comment: What is the problem?  What did you try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
cat file | tr -d "\r" | while read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

Tested on

```
printf "1 2 3\r\n4 5 6\r\n" | tr -d "\r" | while read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

Comment: Don't need cat: `tr -d '\r' < file | while ...`

Comment: @glennjackman Removing CR is needed. Check this out `printf "\r" | ( read line ; echo $line | hd; )`. It will be very painful if we want to use numbers to do some calculations in shell.

Comment: @Grzegorz: removing the CR is needed, but the `cat` command is not. See [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uucaletter).